# System.OperationCanceledException: The agent is stopped or has been stopped, no additional provocateurs can be created

Tags: masstransit

I have many apps (around 80) running in their own docker containers. They all create bus control.
I'm using rabbit transport.

When I start all containers including rabbit at the same time, some apps seems to have issues with initializing bus control properly. All messages produce the OperationCanceledException. Not seeing other warnings/errors logged during app start up. Restart the container fix the issue. I think this started to happen after upgrade from 5.5 to 6.2.

stack trace:

> MassTransit.RequestCanceledException: The request was canceled, RequestId: 0b1c0000-0001-0c00-dec8-08d7daa945f5
>    ---> System.OperationCanceledException: The agent is stopped or has been stopped, no additional provocateurs can be created.
>      at GreenPipes.Caching.Internals.NodeValueFactory`1.CreateValue()
>      at GreenPipes.Caching.Internals.NodeTracker`1.AddNode(INodeValueFactory`1 nodeValueFactory)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at MassTransit.Clients.ClientRequestHandle`1.SendRequest()
>      at MassTransit.Clients.ResponseHandlerConnectHandle`1.GetTask()

I use autofac to inject the IBusControl instance, the creation of it looks like this:

```
bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(rabbit =>
{
rabbit.Durable = true;
rabbit.Host(new Uri(serverUri), h =>
{
    h.Username(settings.Username);
    h.Password(settings.Password);
});

rabbit.PrefetchCount = settings.ReceiverPrefetchCount;  

rabbit.UseMessageScheduler(SchedulerQueueUri);
rabbit.UseAppMetrics(metrics);
rabbit.BusObserver(observer);

foreach (var receiveEndpoint in receiveEndpoints)
{
    rabbit.ReceiveEndpoint(receiveEndpoint.Queue, rec =>
    {
        ConfigureCommonFilters(componentContext, brokerSettings, rec);
        rec.PrefetchCount = brokerSettings.ReceiverConcurrencyLimit;

        foreach (var endpointAction in receiveEndpoint.EndpointActions)
        {
            endpointAction(rec, brokerSettings, componentContext);
        }
    });                                 
});
}
```

My service is started using

```
IWebHostBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>().Build().RunAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

In Startup

```
public virtual void Configure(
IWebHostEnvironment env, IApplicationBuilder app, IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime, IServiceProvider serviceProvider
)
{
var busControl = serviceProvider.GetService<IBusControl>();

// other configuration

appLifetime?.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => retry.RunReliably(() => busControl?.Start()));
appLifetime?.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => retry.RunReliably(() => busControl?.Stop()));
```

}

Comment: `OperationCanceledException` is thrown when the task is cancelled. Posting your bus startup code would really help.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev Edited to include bus creation code.

Comment: Yeah, but where does it start and where does it stop? If you use containers, I assume you use .NET Core, we have proper integration for that and I can't see any of it in your code.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev Edited to include Startup code, thanks.

Comment: So, why don't you use the hosted service? I don't think that attaching startup and shutdown code to the application lifecycle is a good idea.